# Antiforgery token not present after refreshing partial view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I'm having a problem with the anti-forgery token not being present on POST, but this only after I have refreshed the displayed data via a partial view, prior to refreshing the data the token is present and valid. I've tried to outline my issue in detail, but if some code would be more helpful I'm happy to provide some?

I have a page with 2 tables. The first table (the summary view table) is a summary of items displayed in the second table, and clicking on the rows in the summary view refreshes the data in the second table (the detail view table). The data in the summary view is rendered directly on the  page using a foreach loop, but the data in the detail view is rendered via a partial view to allow me to refresh the data without refreshing the whole page.

In the detail view table it's possible to update some of the values in each of the rows by entering edit mode and then triggering the form submit event via a button click. This works fine on initial page load, I can add new rows to the detail view and modify the new or existing rows without any problems. However, once I refresh the data in the detail view by clicking on a summary view row and attempt to update any of the values, I receive `_The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.`

On checking the page source the anti-forgery token is present, however the value changes on each refresh of the partial view, even if I load the same set of data. If I copy the token from the original page (before I reload the partial view) and load the same set of details, I can modify the page source and replace the new token with the previous token and I'm then able to successfully POST the form; mostly...

Checking the `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie shows no change to the cookie value in between refreshing the detail view, so the problem seems to lie with the token value in the partial view, but where this is exactly and how to resync the value with the cookies token, I have no idea.

Has anyone experienced/resolved a similar issue before? I've found one post that was similar to my issue, but there were no responses and it was posted back in 2016. I've reached out to the OP but I'm not confident of a timely response, so I'm hoping someone else has dealt with anti-forgery tokens inside of partial views before and can point me in the right direction.

In case it matters, I'm using form actions to submit the data, not JavaScript/ajax. Ideally I'd like to stick with this, but if this is where the issue lies then I have no problem changing my implementation.

If some code would help understand the issue more, please let me know and I'd be happy to post some.

Thanks in advance for any asistance with this.

```
[HttpGet]
public  ActionResult  ShowTimesheet(long  timesheetId)
{
    return  PartialView("_TimeEntriesPartial",
    _timesheetService.GetById(timesheetId).TimeEntries);
}
```

#### View

```
<tbody >
    @Html.Partial("_TimeEntriesPartial", Model.Timesheet.TimeEntries);
</tbody>
```

#### Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectTime.Model.Entities.TimeEntry>
@foreach (var  TimeEntry  in  Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTimeEntry", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id  =  TimeEntry.Id }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <tr>
        columns...
        <td>Controls for switching mode and submitting item</td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the token plugged into the page? In the main view or one of the child partials and how are you refreshing the partial view?

A reduced code example that shows the structure (without every single field in the views) might help express what's going on =)

Comment: The token is contained in the partial view, and the partial is refreshed with data when clicking one of the rows in the summary section.

I'll prep a code sample and get it added asap. Thanks.

Comment: When you say *refreshed* how is it refreshed, a full reload of the page, or by AJAX that sends down HTML and replaces that entire segment of the mark-up generated by the initial View?

Comment: The click event calls a controller action that loads the data related to the row that was clicked, then the partial view is returned using `return PartialView("viewName", object)`

Comment: Hi, I've added a code sample but if you need to see more of it, just let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the root cause of the problem was because I was injecting a form into a table, which isn't valid Html. When I did this outside of the table it works.